# Smell after engine change?

Tags: engine, smell

I recently changed my car engine and when I have the windows down I notice a rubbery smell which comes into the car.

Any idea what this might be and what I should do about it?

Comment: is the engine used one?did you check no rubber part like liners etc are loose and not touching the engine

Comment: Are all the belts correctly adjusted? clean? in good condition?

Comment: @DhKo yes, it's a used one. I haven't but I don know to.  It wasn't a diy job but the mechanic said he drive it for 20 miles and he thought all was ok.

Comment: @SolarMike Again no idea about these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an engine change it's not unusual to get the odd oil or fluid smell, as any spilt or residual fluids evaporate from hot parts. However this should not last long, sometimes following the next few start ups you'll get a little whiff of the same smell but it should subside quickly after that.

If we're talking days since the engine swap you need to start checking around for fluid leaks, and also making sure there's nothing rubbing against any hot surfaces etc.